# Send signal to another process

Tags: node.js, process, signals

I have two programs, program 'a' written in C and program 'b' in nodeJS. Program 'a' runs in infinite loop and program 'b' runs from time to time to do some data processing. When program 'b' is done I need it to send signal to program 'a' to interrupt the infinite loop and do some other tasks.

program 'a':

```
void my_func(int sig) {
   //do something else
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   (void) signal(SIGUSR1, my_func); 
   while(1){
      //something
      //when received SIGUSR1 jump to my_func
   }
}
```

program 'b':

```
function some_processing(callback) {
   //send SIGUSR1 to program 'a' from here
}
```

My question is, how do I send a signal from nodeJS? I've done some googling and all I could find was signaling its own child processes but not entirely different ones.

Comment: How about [`process.kill`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah thats what I was looking for! Also, is there a way to send signal by process' name, not PID?

Comment: Processes don't really have a "name" in POSIX, it's usually only `argv[0]`. Therefore multiple processes could have the same "name".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So for example, I know my program is /home/user/prog so first I need to find its PID trough something like `ps`?

Comment: Yes that's correct. You could simplify it by having the program print its pid though.